# How to get data with rest API and post it in odoo view?

Tags: api, express, odoo

I have created a rest API with ExpressJs to get data from an external database and I want to post it in Odoo view.

I am facing some difficulties while connecting the API with Odoo and posting the data in Odoo view.

I need just a simple basic example.

```
class Cars(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/CarGClassWaitIn', auth='user')
    def list(self, **kwargs):

        # car = http.request.env['reporting.gclass']
        # cars = car.search([])    
        # return http.request.render('localhost:8000/CarGClassWaitIn')
        response = http.request.render('GET', "localhost:8000/CarGClassWaitIn")

        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            return print("Succesful connection with API.")
        elif response.status_code == 404:
            return print("Unable to reach URL.")
        else:
            return print("Unable to connect API or retrieve data.")

        for record in data:
            return print(record['name'])
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with the `XML-RPC` API, Find more detailed information here [Odoo XMl-RPC](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/webservices/odoo.html)

You have to set up the connection and from the RPC-call have a predefined method like `create, write, delete, search` with use you can perform option in odoo.